# How much time does calling CDN jquery add?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cdn

I'm wondering if anyone has any insight into how much time per page load is added by calling out to:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Specificically, I want to know how much time is added **the second time someone visits the same page** from adding a call to the google hosted jquery, as opposed to:

1. Not loading jquery
2. Loading jquery from a page hosted wherever the html page is located
3. Loading jquery from a locally stored file (if the html page is loaded form a locally stored page, such as in a chrome extension).

So if you read between the lines of my question, what I **really** want to know, whether calling out to the CDN jquery is faster or slower than loading the page locally.

I've always heard that the CDN jquery is fast because it is cached.  My question is pointing toward trying to understand how this caching works?

Edit in response to downvotes:

I am interesting in this answer, regardless of whether it has any noticable or "practical" significance.  I am trying to develop a better mental model of how caching works in this context along with how the browser loads and parses locally hosted javascript.

Comment: The short answer is: the browser saves a copy to disk and grabs that copy instead of downloading it over the Internet. The long answer would require details about individual browser implementations.

Comment: Unless the page is going to be loading from local only, it's not going to make a difference. The user is still going to have to make a request to your site to load jQuery which should take about the same time as loading it from a CDN.

Comment: The benefit of using that CDN is that a user that has visited another website that uses the same one (the exact same version, and everything), they'd _already_ have the resource cached, so they won't need to download jQuery again. For most cases, it'd be negligable difference where you decide to store the library, though.

Comment: You're also overlooking that the CDN could supply a copy from a cache server nearer to your client (think Akamai), so when it's not in the local cache it may not even get it from your server if a cached copy exists nearer.

Comment: Telling me there isnt much of a difference is a non-answer.  I know.  I want to know whether ONCE THE CDN version is cached, whether it is faster to load a locally stored version of JS or call to the CDN version that has been cached.

Comment: Locally is always going to be faster, it's already on the machine!

Comment: @Lloyd, isnt the cached version also on the machine?

Comment: @J-B-L: What do you mean by *locally* vs *cached*. You can cache at multiple levels, by *locally* I assumed you mean the *local browser cache*. That's generally usually faster than calling out over a network.

Comment: @Lloyd That is the question I am asking...  When I call out to the CDN version, does it get cached in such a way that the page will load that LOCAL version (upon second visit) faster/slower than loading a version saved locally at the same directory location as html page being loaded?

Comment: For all practical intents and purposes the loading time of local files, whether they are in the cache or in the filesystem, is instantaneous to the user. It's highly unlikely that there would be a measurable difference.

Comment: @J-B-L the answer to your last question is they will be both be essentially the same. So fast that you should not waste another second worrying about which is faster. See my answer for more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second time someone visits your page the file will be cached, so in your scenarios it would be roughly

1. A couple ms
2. Same
3. Same

The nice things about CDNs is that if you use a popular one the user will **already** have it cached, meaning that their *first* page load will also be faster. They are also likely to have a sever closer to the user.

TL;DR

Use the CDN.

Comment: I'm pretty annoyed generally that this question has been downvoted.  This does not answer my question.  I didn't ask "would it be smart for me to worry about ___."  I asked "which would be faster?"  If nobody here knows the answer, that's fine.  But not knowing the answer doesn't mean that the answer is "stupid."  Is there a SO rule that says that the right answer is always the answer of PRACTICAL import?  Am I confused?  Why is it inappropriate to ask a question that is logical and interesting, even IF it has no practical significance.

Comment: I don't think your question deserves to be downvoted. I do think everyone including myself assumed that you were looking for the practical answer, so you might want to clarify that in your question.

Comment: If it helps, I did try to measure this or something similar one time and the difference was something like .03 **milliseconds** so when we say essentially the same, we really do mean it.

Comment: That actually does help! Still curious about the answer--Thanks

Comment: @J-B-L Several people have told you that the answer to the "which would be faster" question is "both are equally fast". If you don't believe that it's true, fine, but don't say that you didn't get an answer or that nobody knows the answer.

Answer (score 0):

That really all just depends on how fast the server your html is hosted on is.  Yes CDNs are pretty fast.  But as you indicated, once the browser has cached the resources (the first time a user visits your page), it will be loading the resource from the cache anyway.  In addition, jquery is small.  So small in fact that most hosting platforms will yield similar results.

Answer (score 0):

Considering that the file is highly cached by CDN's, the delivery will be consistently fast.

This is the download speed taken from a metro area:

```
        time_namelookup:  0.005
           time_connect:  0.042
        time_appconnect:  0.203
       time_pretransfer:  0.203
          time_redirect:  0.000
     time_starttransfer:  0.216
                        ----------
             time_total:  0.248 milliseconds

          size_download:  86351 Bytes
         speed_download:  347767.000 B/sec
```